# Eclipse ADT is blocked

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I´m noob with android and I´m using eclipse ADT but often the IDE is block and I have to force the close of eclipse. This message is showed:

[image]

Eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar 
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m 
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685
```

Comment: Show your eclipse.ini file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this might happen for corrupt workspace.. Check this [link](http://spacetech.dk/eclipse-failed-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369.html)